# SharePoint User Sync Up

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Does SharePoint 2016 uses LDAP protocol to sync-up the users with Active Directory?

If yes, where can we configure it to switch from LDAP to LDAP SSL?

Answer (score 0):

The UPSA has an option in your synchronization connection to use LDAP SSL (tcp/636). You can tick that box and AD Import will use LDAPS.

Answer (score 0):

Configure profile synchronization by using SharePoint Active Directory Import in SharePoint Server:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-profile-synchronization-by-using-sharepoint-active-directory-import

Configure Secure LDAP connection on Server 2016:

https://pdhewaju.com.np/2017/03/02/configuring-secure-ldap-connection-server-2016/